# How to distinguish repetition is allowed and not allowed for combination and permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How to distinguish repetition is allowed and not allowed for combination and permutation?

Like how do I distinguish the question whether the repetition is allowed on that question.

Please explain thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the formula or how to know when you should use it?

Comment: when to use it. Like how do I distinguish the question whether the repetition is allowed on that question.

Comment: The key phrase *with replacement* often means repetition is allowed, and *without replacement* that it isn't. However, that only takes care of a minority of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were asked a question like, how many ways can you pick a batting lineup for a baseball team where (following the convention of baseball, I think), you don't have the same player appearing twice in the lineup, that would be a problem that didn't allow repetition. A problem with repetition would be if you could form a batting lineup where the same player appears multiple times, even having a lineup consisting only of one player.

It's harder to tell you when to recognize this so much as to ask you to use your intuition, but in general, you can look at each choice available and ask, "after I make this choice, can I make it again, or can I only make it once?"

Answer (score 0):

The formula for permutations is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$
The formula for combinations is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

(Here I assume you understand the permutation formula a bit). To derive the second from the first let's make an example... say we are finding the combinations of $3$ numbers from a set of $4$, say $1,2,3,$ and $4$. If we use the permutation formula we get our answer as $24$, but we can see we over-counted... for example, $1,2,3$ and $1,3,2$ were counted separately. Since we are taking sets of size $3$ and there are $3!$ ways to arrange a set of size $3$, we have over-counted by a factor of $3!$. Generalizing this, if we use the permutation formula to get combinations we will always over-count by $k!$, where $k$ is the size of the set we take from the whole, and hence the formula for combinations above (we say order does not matter with combinations because of that division... every set we take is unique no matter how we arrange it. This is not true for permutations).